# How to store multiple checkbox values in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, checkbox, laravel-8

I'm new to Laravel and I made a survey form with multiple checkbox to store in the database,
when the form submits it only reads the last  input
here is my Model for it :

```
    protected $fillable = ['Name',
                           'email',
                           'number',
                           'age',
                           'roles',
                           'recommend',
                           'options',
                           'comment'];
 protected $casts = ['options'=>'array'];
```

here is my Controller :

```
User::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('user.index')
    ->with('success','Info Added successfully');
```

Migration :

```
 $table->set ('options', ['Front-end Projects', 'Back-end Projects', 'Data Visualization', 'Challenges',
                     'Open Source Community', 'Gitter help rooms', 'Videos', 'City Meetups', 'Wiki', 'Forum', 'Additional Courses'
        ])->nullable();
```

and that's my Blade :

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Front-end Projects">Front-end Projects
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Back-end Projects">Back-end Projects
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Data Visualization">Data Visualization
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Challenges">Challenges
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Open Source Community">Open Source Community
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Gitter help rooms">Gitter help rooms
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Videos">Videos<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="City Meetups">City Meetups<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Wiki">Wiki<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Forum">Forum<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Additional Courses">Additional Courses<be>
```

here is my table schema:
[table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E3kr.png)

this what I tried and I got this error
[image: Error]

Comment: Please paste your table schema here

Comment: posted it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is make sure the options column is a text field and on setting the attribute make sure it is encoded as a json string and on retrieval make sure it is reverted back to an array.

```
function setOptionsAttribute($values = null)
{
   if(null === $values) {
     $this->attributes['options'] = null;
   }
   $this->attributes['options'] = json_encode($values);
}

function getOptionsAttribute($value)
{
   if(null === $values){
     return null;
   }
   return json_decode($values,true);
}
```

Comment: this didnt work with me unfortunately

Comment: @GhadaAlSarakbi, what didn't work? It didn't get saved in the database, you still get the same error? Did you put my code in the User model?

Comment: yes i did put your code in my Model,and still got the same error when running

Comment: and if you start tinker and add it by hand:
$model = YourModelName::first();
$model->options = ['Front-end Projects','Data Visualization'];
$model->save();

Could you try that and see if it works when checking the database if the data is there.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and it saved to the database but when directing the page I got an error which is ((htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given))

Comment: So in the database is indeed the saved data? Or do you mean it breaks on saving? Could you also show the exact line which gives the error?

Comment: It is saved in the database and the values show correctly in the table, but when submitting the form it directs me to an error page, and  this is the error I'm getting                                {{ ErrorException
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\Users\Ghada\Desktop\Tutorial\survey1\resources\views\user\index.blade.php) }}

Comment: This is a different error. The save is correct and that was the error in the original post I would say. Retrieval of the data and show it is another thing. And as it is an array indeed, you can't echo it as a string. If you want to show all the answers chosen in a text, you could do something like 
{{ implode(', ',$model->options) }}
in your blade file